# Call a function which returns output with all the parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In notifications.js I have a code which takes message parameter and then return the whole output when I call from Flavor.js using http.notificationa(res.data);

But it is not giving desired output to me. Can you tell me what is wrong with this code,please?

Thanks in advance.

```
import { store as notifications } from "react-notifications-component";

function notificationa(message) {
  notifications.addNotification({
    message: message,
    type: "success",
    insert: "top",
    container: "bottom-right",
    dismiss: {
      duration: 5000
    }
  });
}

export default notificationa;
```

Flavor.js

```
import http from "./../Common/notifications";
http.notificationa(res.data);
```

Comment: export default allows a direct reference to a value to be imported in another file. Your import statement should be: `import notificationa from "./../Common/notifications";` Then you can call `notificationa` directly.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPenney. Issue has been solved with your suggestions.